# Developing cross-platform client-server app

Tags: android, ios, client-server, cross-platform

I'm starting a project with a couple friends of mine from my computer science university. We already have a good knowledge of java coding, hence OOP theory and practice, and sure we are not afraid to code in other languages. But we know little about software designing.

To let the things simple let's say we want to build an app, a multiplayer game that needs a server to host the matches. And we would like to have an android user playing against an apple user and/or a PC user. So our first question is: is this possible?

If it is, it would be awesome to write a single server side code the manages all the different clients, wich are written in the code needed to run on their own OS (java for android, c# for wphone, jsp for the web client and swift for iOS). All this different languages are the worst scenario of course, it's just to make the idea clear.

I know this is not all madness, I had the chance to take a look at a the source code of a multiplayer game, where the client was made in python and the server in C++. And with C++ were created the modules to comunicate with the python's methods.

Since we know little about this advanced techniques, and this is a long term thing, we'd like to be told where to look to start from.

As of now I'm not really even sure what to type into Google search to get this informations, and just that would be enough for us to know.

**EDIT**

I do realize it is a broad question, and I'm sorry about that. That's just because not knowing very well what we can do with the tecnologies available it's not simple to ask a simpler and more topic oriented question.

What I can say is that our need are similar to the ones that a trading card game app could need.

- It should be real-time.
- Latency shouldn't be more than 1s
- We'd like to host every match on our servers, to keep track of user progress and take some punishing actions towards bad behaving players (like quitting the match). And I guess it would also be easier to avoid use of hacks.
- The Dabatase it is needed, but not stricly for the purpose of the matches, more to store data about players.

This are some coinstraints that we have in our mind now, it would be awesome if we could be told what to search to get the knowledge or even some explamples, like eee suggested (thanks about that, i'll take a look in to it right away).

Comment: This question seems a little broad. Perhaps you can distill it to a single, more concise, query?

Comment: Agreed, with first commenter. This is very broad. Is it possible? Yes, absolutely. What's the best way to do it? Well, there's about a million different ways to do what you want and we have no idea about constraints. Is it real time? Do you have latency restrictions? Is it a shared environment? Do you need a host, or is everything hosted on a server? Do you need strict database synchronization? Heck, do you even need a database? Go back to the drawing board and break down your idea in to as many pieces as you can and start with the simplest question you can ask and you'll get answers.

Comment: It is possible and it can be done. For beginners, you can look into existing sourcecodes available on Github to learn from. For example: Kouchat for Android and Windows on GitHub.